# ¿Como puedo llamar una función que esta dentro de un Jframe desde otra clase?

Tags: java, poo, jframe

Tengo una función dentro de un `JFrame` llamado prueba. La función lo que hace es hacer visibles unos *labels*, lo que quiero es que esa función se ejecute después de otra función, por lo que necesito que esa línea de código se ejecute desde otra clase.

Esta es mi función dentro del `JFrame`:

```
public void mostrarlbl(){
    jLabel1.setVisible(true);
    jLabel2.setVisible(true);
    lblUS.setVisible(true);
    lblID.setVisible(true);
}
```

Para ejecutarla desde otra clase probé de la siguiente manera:

```
prueba prueba = new prueba();
prueba.mostrarlbl();
```

Y aunque no me da errores de compilación, la función no se ejecuta, igual he probado de la siguiente manera pero tampoco me funciona:

```
prueba.jLabel1.setVisible(true);
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

has intentado heredar los metodos de la clase en la que tienes mostrar a la otra?, si no puedes intenta buscar que es heredar en internet basicamente asi podras tener todos los métodos que tengas en una clase en otra.

Eso se hace con la palabra reservada extends

Comment: Correcto, pero ten en cuenta que la herencia solo hay que usarla cuando sea correcto conceptualmente, cuando realmente haya una relación de herencia entre las clases base e hija. Si solo quieres acceder a un método de otra clase, pero estas no tienen ninguna relación conceptual o lógica, una mejor opción es hacer el método público, o visible a nivel de paquete, según corresponda.

Comment: tienes razón, es que para poder ayudarte seria bueno que muestres todo el código de ambas clases porque no se como estas utilizando la lógica

Comment: Yo no escribí la pregunta xD Pero estás en lo cierto: sin más código no podemos hacer mucho más. Solo lo comentaba para que lo tengas en cuenta en tus proyectos futuros. Que la herencia no hay que usarla por usar. Aunque tu consejo está en lo correcto: con herencia se tiene acceso a los campos protegidos de la clase base.

Answer (score 1):

Estoy casi seguro de que el método se ejecuta correctamente. Seguramente es un problema de visibilidad en pantalla.

Al dibujar cosas a mano, o al modificar algunos elementos de una interfaz java swing, en ocasiones, la interfaz no se pinta correctamente en la pantalla.

En general, se soluciona repintando un elemento contenedor (que puede ser el `JFrame`) o invalidándolo, lo que fuerza a que se revalide y se repinte.

En primer lugar, la ventana debe de estar visible para que los cambios tengan efectos:

```
Prueba ventana = new Prueba();
ventana.setVisible(true);
prueba.mostrarLabel();
```

Y en segundo lugar, revalidas o repintas el contenedor dentro del método `mostrarLabel`:

```
public void mostrarLabel()
{
    // Tus modificaciones en la UI
    jLabel1.setVisible(true);
    jLabel2.setVisible(true);
    lblUS.setVisible(true);
    lblID.setVisible(true);

    // Revalidar y repintar
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

En ocasiones solo es necesario llamar a uno de los dos métodos (`revalidate` o `repaint`), y a veces es necesario colocar las dos llamadas.

Ten en cuenta también que esa etiqueta debe haber sido añadida al `JFrame`, de manera directa (al `contentPane`) o indirecta (a un contenedor que está dentro de la ventana), por ejemplo en el constructor.

```
public Prueba() {
    // Código previo de asignar título a la ventana, etc.
    JLabel etiquetaInicialmenteInvisible = new JLabel("Invisible");
    contentPane.add(etiquetaInicialmenteInvisible, ...);    // Más argumentos
    etiquetaInicialmenteInvisible.setVisible(false);
    // Más cóigo de creación de la UI
}
```

Comment: Pues acabo de comprobar que tienes razón, y la función si se esta ejecutando correctamente, pero al momento de ejecutar esta línea: ventana.setVisible(true);
Se me habré otra ventana con los labels ya visibles. La cuestión es que quisiera que los labels se muestran en la misma ventana donde tengo todo.

Comment: La ventana, o `JFrame`, solo lo debes hacer visible una vez, tras crearlo. Me da la impresión de que estás creando otro objeto de tipo `Prueba`, lo que es lo mismo que crear otra ventana nueva con el mismo contenido. Crea un solo objeto ventana, hazlo visible después de crearlo. Y después, en el punto donde invocas al método que hace visible los _label_, repinta la ventana, el mismo objeto ventana que creaste al principio. No crees otra ventana con `new Prueba()`.